# How to validate a formset in dajngo

Tags: python, django, validation, formset

I am using formset to input my data into the database but for some reason it just doesn't validate, whenever I test in the terminal and call the .is_valid() It just returns false no matter what I try. Here's the code in my views.py and forms.py . Any help will be much appreciated!

```
# Advanced Subjects (Advanced Biology)
def form_5_entry_biology_view(self, request):
    current_teacher = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    logged_school = current_teacher.school_number
    students_involved = User.objects.get(school_number=logged_school).teacher.all()
    data = {"student_name": students_involved}
    formset_data = AdvancedStudents.objects.filter(class_studying="Form V", combination="PCB")
    student_formset = formset_factory(AdvancedBiologyForm, extra=0)
    initial = []
    for element in formset_data:
        initial.append({"student_name": element})
    formset = student_formset(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
    print(formset.is_valid())
    context = {
        "students": students_involved,
        "formset": formset,
        "class_of_students": "Form V",
        "subject_name": "Advanced Biology",
    }
    return render(request, "analyzer/marks_entry/marks_entry_page.html", context)
```

And here is my forms.py

```
class AdvancedBiologyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    student_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = ResultsALevel
        fields = ('student_name', 'advanced_biology_1', 'advanced_biology_2', 
                   'advanced_biology_3',)
```

Comment: Well, after running `.is_valid()`, you might want to `print(formset.errors)` too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using `request.POST` and `is_valid()` you probably want to check if there actually is a post request or if the page is just viewed:

```py
def form_5_entry_biology_view(self, request):
    current_teacher = User.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    logged_school = current_teacher.school_number
    students_involved = User.objects.get(school_number=logged_school).teacher.all()
    data = {"student_name": students_involved}
    formset_data = AdvancedStudents.objects.filter(class_studying="Form V", combination="PCB")

    # Here you are creating the formset using the model
    student_formset = formset_factory(AdvancedBiologyForm, extra=0)

    # Here you are generating your initial data
    initial = []
    for element in formset_data:
        initial.append({"student_name": element})

    # Here you are using the initial data to create pre-populated
    # forms with it using the formset.
    # These forms will be displayed when the page loads.
    formset = student_formset(initial=initial)

    context = {
        "students": students_involved,
        "formset": formset,
        "class_of_students": "Form V",
        "subject_name": "Advanced Biology",
    }

    # But if the user hits the "submit"-Button...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ... you don't want to have the formset with your
        # initial data. Instead you want the entries by the user
        # which are transmitted in request.POST to populate the
        # formset forms.
        formset = student_formset(request.POST or None)
        # Now you can validate the formset with the fields which
        # got input the the user; not the "initial" data like in
        # your original code
        if formset.is_valid():
            # This runs formset validation.
            # You can define your own formset validations like
            # you would for models/forms.
            for form in formset:
                # And / Alternatively:
                # you could in theory also add another "if form.is_valid():" in here
                # This would trigger any validation on the
                # model/form; not the validators on the formset.
                form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(...
    return render(request, "analyzer/marks_entry/marks_entry_page.html", context)
```

Otherwise you might call `is_valid()` on an unbound form.
From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/):

> If the form is submitted using a POST request, the view will once again create a form instance and populate it with data from the request: form = NameForm(request.POST) This is called “binding data to the form” (it is now a bound form).

Basically if a form is empty it's unbound, and if it's populated with data it gets bound after POST. When you open a page and immediately try "is_valid()" it will basically always be false as you are checking if an empty form is valid; which it likely never is.

To point out the error:

```py
formset = student_formset(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
print(formset.is_valid())
```

This is not valid. Because initial values are not equal to populating a form field with "real" values. So what happens is that it tries to populate the fields in the form with `request.POST or None`.
But you don't have a `if request.method == 'POST':` condition. So your code will just run through before hitting the last line of code which is the return statement displaying the page.
This means that your code validates `request.POST or None` before the user even saw the page. So there is no way a user could have already entered data and hit submit. Which means there is no POST-request, so it always turns `None`. So you are basically calling `is_valid()` on a form that has no field values in it which leads to the validation failing.

EDIT 1: I just noticed in your `forms.py` you have written:

```
fields = ('student_name', 'advanced_biology_1', 'advanced_biology_2', 
                   'advanced_biology_3',)
```

This [should be a list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead:

```
fields = ['student_name', 'advanced_biology_1', 'advanced_biology_2', 
                   'advanced_biology_3',]
```

EDIT 2: fixed wrong variable name
EDIT 3: added extensive comments to clarify what's happening in the code
EDIT 4: pointed out cause of problem more distinctly.

Comment: I didn't get this part                                                                                                               
    if student_form.is_valid():
            for form in student_form:                                                                                                 What were you referring at?

Comment: @Raxan7 Sorry for the confusion, my bad. It was meant to be "formset" instead of "student_form". Don't know how I came up with that wrong name. I edited the code accordingly.